# Connection.Execute vs QueryDef.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, dao

Using `acedao` in `VBA`, what's better to use for executing stored aprocedure on an `SQL` server database between:

```
connection.execute(sql)
```

and

```
querydef.execute(sql)
```

I need to run command, retrieve `RecordSet` or single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally do it in this way:

```
Set MyDB= DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("", False, False, connString)
MyDB.Execute SQLstring, dbSQLPassThrough
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure will be in the SQLServer database so I would suggest that connection.exectute would be better. To run the other you'll need to set up a querydef in your Access database that contains the SQL to run the stored procedure which seems like a duplication of effort. The querydef.exectute takes options, not a SQL string.